# Accessing user roles client side

Tags: jquery, asp.net, roles, webmethod

I am trying to figure out an efficient way of limiting a user's permissions based on their roles.  I am using ASP.NET `WebMethod`s to pass data via jQuery AJAX.  I use a custom role provider that stores the user's roles in an ASP encrypted cookie.  I can access these roles by using

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("rolename")
```

For the majority of my requests, I send back a JSON serialized DataTable, and then build the HTML in jQuery.  Basically, I'd like to (while building the HTML) find out if the user is in a role, then disable a button or grey out a field.

Originally I thought that I could pass the roles to an `asp:Hiddenfield` from the master page, but that stores a plaintext array in my page markup

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create an object that includes both the DataTable and the permission data?

```
{"canEdit":"true", "canDelete":"false", "dataTable": ...}
```

Keep in mind that permission *logic* should be performed server-side (and should be performed again when the user tries to perform an operation), so it makes sense to only send the client-side information on which buttons to disable.

Comment: I like this answer.  I have a static method that converts a DataTable to JSON, If I made an object with those properties it would serialize nicely.  AND I would only have to pass back the roles needed for those elements.  Nice.